# Create Submodule From A Few Folders in One Repo - Way To Track

Tags: git, azure-devops

we have one big repo with code from last 10 year (Original Repo).

We want to re-use some of this code with several other projects, mostly in a few folders from Repo A. So I would like to make a new Core Repo and have these new projects use it as a submodule.  Eventually can update Original Repo to use Core repo, but not initially.

Ideally would like a link from Core Repo to Original Repo (for the folders that I decided to bring over), but don't want to Fork the entire Original Repo and bring in a bunch of extra stuff.  Would I need to do this?

Other option is to make a new clean repo for Core Repo, and then do new commits of what I want in there, and then add a new Remote to be able to see changes - is this possible, if there's only a few folders?

Any other ideas/options?  Using Azure DevOps git btw.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a new Build Pipeline for the Core code and publish it via an internal Nuget or NPM package.  You could move it to a separate repository but you don't have to. Then you can consume the package wherever you need it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/artifacts-overview?view=azure-devops

Comment: appreciate the response but doesn't really address what I want to do, has nothing to do with pipelines with azure devops... using git...

Comment: Then I'm a little confused by what the end goal is.  It sounded like you want other options for breaking apart a large repo and using the core code in separate solutions.